# ZF2 multiple module base path

Tags: php, zend-framework2

On Zend Framework 2, I am trying to set different base_paths in the view manager for each module in the framework. However, the base_path I set for the last module is the one that is being applied. How can I set module specific base_paths for ZF2?

This is how I am setting the base path in each module.config.php:

```
'view_manager' => array(
    'base_path' => '/zend/modulename/',
    'display_not_found_reason' => true,
    'display_exceptions'       => true,
    'doctype'                  => 'HTML5',
    'not_found_template'       => 'error/404',
    'exception_template'       => 'error/index',
    'template_map' => array(
        'layout/layout'           => __DIR__ . '/../view/layout/layout.phtml',
        'layout/guest'           => __DIR__ . '/../view/layout/guest.phtml',
        'modulename/index/index'  => __DIR__ . '/../view/modulename/index/index.phtml',
        'error/404'               => __DIR__ . '/../view/error/404.phtml',
        'error/index'             => __DIR__ . '/../view/error/index.phtml',
    ),
    'template_path_stack' => array(
        __DIR__ . '/../view',
    ),
),
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you don't need to set base path for your module. If you have Module.php in your module src folder, then you can use **DIR** or relative path from Module.php.

Comment: This is for the views though, to put in the header so the proper URLs are created for scripts and stylesheets, not a relative path for accessing the PHP.

Comment: Aaah yes, sorry. Problem here is that configuration is array based and it could be overwritten everywhere (and view_manager is shared within all modules). I suggest to move base_path up higher in tree without module name and then specify module name in template_map (__DIR__.'/modulename/../view...').

Comment: Also best practise solution for you will be to use some asset management. In my projects I'm using **[rwoverdijk/assetmanager](https://github.com/RWOverdijk/AssetManager)** which is pretty easy to implement and you could have all your asset only encapsulated inside your module directory without another overwhelm in disk space or performance.